# electrons in elecrtostatic force(please read specification given below)

Tags: electrostatics

when comb is rubbed with hair, and brought near small pieces of papers, small paper pieces gets a towards comb. Here the comb gets negatively charged and when brought near piece of paper where do electrons go because after sometime attraction of paper pieces towards comb stops and comb doesnt have negative charge then. Why does it happen so ? What is the reason for it ?

If a glass rod is rubbed with silk, rodna and silk gets positive or negative charge respectively, an when they are seperated after charge gets nuetral. Why does it happens? What is the reason behind this ?

Comment: this is not duplicate here i am talking about what happen to electrons ? John rennie and  Qmechanics have my question properly